# Attempt to read property "name" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Moja_OTT\resources\views\premium\profile.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want a simple program that shows the user profile after login. I used session and middleware. But it is saying that the name property is null. Please help me solve this error. I have used User model. The value of the properties are not retrieving from the database.

Blade code:

```
<h1>Profile</h1>

<h2>Welcome Mr/Ms {{$user->name}}</h2>

<a href="{{route('logout')}}">Logout</a>
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Models\PremiumModel;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id'; 
    protected $timestamp = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'type',
        'email_verified_at',
        'pro_pic',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
     
    function admin()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\admin', 'user_id', 'admin_id');
    }
    function premium()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PremiumModel::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
function profile()
{
    $user = User::where('user_id',session()->get('logged'))->first();
    return view('premium.profile')->with('user',$user);
    
    
}
```

Here, `logged` is the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `hasOne` in the User model:

```
public function premium()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PremiumModel::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Because hasMany returned an array, but hasOne returned just a single Object

Comment: And I suggest you are using `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()`, this return all information about Authenticated user